# Wrong ruby/gemset/local variable version using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, environment-variables, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently, I try to deploy my Rails 4 project with capistrano. At the moment, the server is the same as the host, but different users are used. The issue is that capistrano does not load RVM AND local variables correctly, at the same time.
The local variable is set in `/etc/profile.d/oracle.sh`

```
set :default_shell, "bash -l"
set :rvm_ruby_string, "ruby-2.0.0-p0@rails4"
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :use_sudo: false
...
...
desc "tester"
task :tester, hosts: "localhost" do
  run "echo $TNS_ADMIN"
  run "ruby -v"
  run "gem list"
end
```

If I use this settings, I get:

```
echo $TNS_ADMIN --> "correct path"
ruby -v --> 2.0.0p195 (wrong version)
gem list --> 5 gems (wrong)
```

If I do not use `set :default_shell, "bash -l"`, I get:

```
echo $TNS_ADMIN --> "" (wrong)
ruby -v --> 2.0.0p0 (correct version)
gem list --> > 100 gems (correct)
```

If I use `set :default_shell, :bash`, I get:

```
echo $TNS_ADMIN --> "" (wrong)
ruby -v --> 1.9.3p194 (wrong version = ruby version of the system)
gem list --> > 5 gems (wrong)
```

If I do not use `set :rvm_ruby_string`, I get the same wrong result like using both lines (`set :default_shell, "bash -l"` and `set :rvm_ruby_string, "..."`)

But I would like to have the local variable `$TNS_ADMIN` set and the correct ruby/gemset (2.0.0p0@rails with > 100 gems).
What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the first line:

```
set :default_shell, "bash -l"
```

it disables `rvm-capistrano` integration.

You can read the variable with:

```
run "source  /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh; echo $TNS_ADMIN"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. It there a possibility to source this file for most/every run command? Maybe, I need some other variables in future. It would be nice to have the same ENV as the user of the server.